# "Best Trainee Turner competition" vs. "competition for the title of 'Best Student Turner'"

Tags: synonyms, proper-nouns

Which sentence is better?

1. He achieved a good place in the regional Best Trainee Turner competition.
2. He achieved a good place in the regional competition for the title of 'Best Student Turner'.

Answer (score 2):

"To achieve a good place" is an odd sounding construction. I think either sentence could be improved by replacing that construction with something more specific like:

> He placed in the top half among competitors in the regional Best Trainee Turner competition.

or

> He came in X place in the regional competition for the title of 'Best Student Turner'.

...where X is an ordinal number such as first, second, third, etc.